# MS Acces query not updateable

Tags: ms-access

I have table for `Users` that contains a budget for training, ID=Primary Key

```
ID | UserID | FName | SName | Dept | Budget
 1 |   1    | John  | Smith |  CS  |  1000
 2 |   2    | Ian   | Caine |  CS  |  2500
 3 |   3    | Jane  | Kelly |  ED  |  1000
 4 |   1    | John  | Smith |  EQ  |  1000
 5 |   2    | Ian   | Caine |  EQ  |  2500
 6 |   3    | Jane  | Kelly |  CS  |  1000
```

I then have another table `Courses` that stores the course they have taken, ID=Primary Key;

```
ID | UserID | Course | Date    | Dept |Cost  
1  |   1    |  CS01  | 1/4/18  | CS   | 100
2  |   2    |  CS01  | 1/4/18  | CS   | 100
3  |   1    |  CS02  | 10/4/18 | CS   | 75
4  |   2    |  CS02  | 10/4/18 | CS   | 75
5  |   1    |  CS01  | 1/4/18  | EQ   | 100
```

I am using this query to combine the two so I can add courses to for each user and see their remaining budget;

```
SELECT u.UserID, c.Date, c.Cost, 
       u.Budget -
       DSum("sub.Cost", "tbl_Courses", "ID <= " & c.ID & 
                                       " AND UserID = " & c.UserID &  
                                       " AND Dept = '" & c.Dept & "'") AS [Budget Remaining]
FROM tbl_Users u
INNER JOIN tbl_Courses AS c
   ON u.UserID = c.UserID AND u.Dept = c.Dept
```

You can download the database [Here](http://s664318443.websitehome.co.uk/database7.accdb)

However, the resulting query is not updateable, I have checked against the common reasons why a query is not updateable from the link;

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html

but fail to see the error or solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is correctly stated in the link you gave:

> The fields in a JOIN are not indexed correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.

That reason is often valid when joining on multiple columns, since if the fields were unique indexes, then there likely wouldn't be a need to join on two fields. In your case, *UserID* is not uniquely indexed in the table *Courses*, and *Dept* is not uniquely indexed in both tables.

Without more information, I can't advice you how to make this query updateable, but it's likely that that's plain not possible.